# Surpress all errors on a specific request in Codeigniter

Tags: php, debugging, codeigniter

I'm developing a JSON integrated web application, which is really irritating to debug on client-side when I'm getting some (some intended) PHP error's on the serverside of the (through ajax) page request. For debugging purposes I would like to disable all my debugging of PHP and DB related errors for only this specific page / view / controller.

I've already tried placing the following in the top of my controller, which should be working according to some articles I found on the interwebs:

```
function index() {
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    $this->config->set_item('log_threshold', 0);
```

Though, this still gives me the darn errors.

I know it sounds silly that I would require the errors to be disabled, but... just trust me on this one.

Comment: did you set `error_reporting` off ?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the error reporting using a .`htaccess` file?

Comment: I did try ini_setting the error_reporting off, but that did not help. I did not try Sheikh Heera's solution though. I'll be trying that later today!

Comment: Hi, i always use this when using Ajax request: @error_reporting(0); at the top of the ajax handler function. Let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: Tried the _@$this->config->set_item('log_threshold', 0);_, tried the _@error_reporting(0)_. Still no luck... Still getting warnings and errors from code that is underneath the error disabling.

Answer (score 3):

Have you changed ENVIRONMENT constant to 'production' in index.php?
It will turn off all errors

> In production environments, it is typically desirable to disable PHP's
>   error reporting by setting the internal error_reporting flag to a
>   value of 0. This disables native PHP errors from being rendered as
>   output, which may potentially contain sensitive information.
>
> Setting CodeIgniter's ENVIRONMENT constant in index.php to a value of
>   'production' will turn off these errors. In development mode, it is
>   recommended that a value of 'development' is used. More information
>   about differentiating between environments can be found on the
>   Handling Environments page.

If it won't help - try to update CodeIgniter.

By the way, this

```
$this->config->set_item('log_threshold', 0);
```

is just file logging.

If you need to turn off only on one page try this one

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
error_reporting(0);
define('MP_DB_DEBUG', false);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that won't do me any good, it's really about disabling the reporting for just one view.

Comment: I've edited my post...try these 3 instructions...maybe it will help

Comment: i have found this solution after weeks of pain in the a**